# jquery append css to head

Tags: jquery, css

I wanted to learn some jQuery and I tried to start with something simple (or that's what I thought anyway), I'm trying to change some `div` style with some css but it does not seem to work.
Any ideas regarding what I am doing wrong?

```js
$('head').append('<style type="text/css"> #main1, #main2 { 
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #92FE9D, #00C9FF) !important;
color: #000000 !important;
border-radius: 4; } 
</style>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main1">1</div>
<div id="main2">2</div>
```

Comment: Please explain how it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate new lines like:

```
$('head').append('<style type="text/css"> #main1, #main2 {'+
'background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #92FE9D, #00C9FF) !important;'+
'color: #000000 !important;'+
'border-radius: 4; }'+
'</style>');
```

Comment: oh yup you would be right thank you for the help and the very useful info

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change some css property with CSS you need to do it this way for example:

```
$("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your CSS into a template string using two backticks:

```js
var css = `
<style type="text/css"> 
    #main1, #main2 { 
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #92FE9D, #00C9FF) !important;
        color: #000000 !important;
        border-radius: 4; 
    } 
</style>`;

$('head').append(css);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main1">1</div>
<div id="main2">2</div>
```